# Stack Exchange Data Explorer not fully working

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

Possibly an after-effect of this from yesterday [linkage](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83181/chat-and-blog-and-sede-servers-down).

So, in the SEDE and run a query. All OK. Next, run another (not logged in) and get a CAPTCHA request, apart from one small problem - no captcha is displayed. [image: no captcha]

So I think "Fine, I'll log in". Sign in using my AOL OpenID, get this far:
[image: aol OpenID login]

and then click on "continue" and see...[image: server errorz]

Not sure if it's just an AOL OID problem.

Windows 7, 32-bit. Internet Explorer 8, ~9:36 UTC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to say this is OK now.